# When export my character to Mixamo it looks different

Tags: rendering, animation, mesh, import

It was made in Blender

[image]

[image]

[Character file](https://files.fm/u/7dy8dqr6q)

Comment: check ur blender again you might have two hair meshes but the mixamo problem is somthin i got too

Comment: Aside from the missing textures - which is easily explained because you didn't included them in any way in your export - the only difference remaining it the yellow part of your hair, but it's hard to tell how things went from your .blend to your FBX without your original blend file. Though, honestly, why do you even care? The only reason you send a model to Mixamo is to get a rig and maybe some animations. You don't need  to care about materials at all.